# How to determine whether an integer is zero or not, without using logical negation or control structures

Tags: c, binary

How to use bit-level operation (~ ^ & | >> <<), logical operation (&& || but cannot use !), and arithmetic operation (+ - * /) to finish this function (C language).

```
int isZero(int a){
  //if a == 0, return 1, if a != 0, return 0
}
```

or

```
bool isZero(int a){
  // if a == 0, return true, if a != 0, return false
}
```

if, for, while statements cannot be used, operation like ==, != cannot be used.

comment: someone give a solution:


 
`boolean isZero(int a) {return a;}`


However, the trick is if a is equal to zero, we need return 1(or true), and we cannot use ! operation.

Comment: What do you mean - 'to know'? How the knowledge is to be used?

Comment: you mean something like `int isZero = (int)(input == 0);`?

Comment: sorry, I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Why are you not using valid c operators?

Comment: Try to implement negation without using ! operator.

Comment: Why would you want to implement logical negation without using the ! operator? It should be supported by every C compiler, and if you try and implement it in a different way you may well end up with the same output code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way, no 'forbidden' operators.

```
int isZero(unsigned int n)
{
  return (((n | (~n + 1)) >> 31) & 1) ^ 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the boolean cast operator `(bool)x` is usually written `!!x`, it's also possible to write it as `x&&x` (or, equivalently, `x||x`). Once `x` has been cast to a bool -- that is, a 0 or a 1 --, it can be inverted simply by subtracting it from 1. So:

```
int isZero(unsigned int n) { return 1 - (n&&n); }
```

Of course, you could use `^` to invert, if you weren't allowed arithmetic operators:

```
int isZero(unsigned int n) { return 1 ^ (n&&n); }
```